# How to use HTTP keep-alive in asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, timeout, keep-alive

I have one web page that is built by asp.net and to load data from database to show on.
But when the data to be loaded is so much, user accesses this page and has to wait till 20 secs, and time out is happened. He cannot see a result.

I want to increase the timeout or turn on Http Keep-alive or do something to user can get to see the result.

I have tried to Enable HTTP Keep-Alive in IIS7, but still be not resolved.
Anybody give me some idea please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to show all the data on the first page, or would it be possible to use paging so that you only load the first 10, or 50, or 100 rows from the database? Your users will probably also find that an easier design to work with, rather than having to pick an item out of thousands of rows.

There's lots of questions on here about how to do data paging in ASP.NET and lots of articles on the internet too:
[Stack Overflow ASP.NET paging](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=paging%20asp.net)
[Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data (asp.net)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of timeout you are experiencing.

If the timeout is happening while executing the query, you can try increasing the timeout of the Command object: sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;

If the timeout is related to ajax, increase the ScriptManager timeout: AsyncPostBackTimeout="120"

Answer (score 0):

phi,
Nothing is required. All you have to do is make sure your IIS doesnt goto sleep mode for that particular website. So enable Keep-Alive for that website using the IIS properties(is available from ver.IIS 6.1 to 8). Moreover an external pinger needs to be working jus like the cron-job activity in linux.
In that case you can make use of "[PingAlive.com](http://PingAlive.com)" which is FREE to use. Jus' add sites and it will look after that your website never goes down(until your default page of the website will be working fine).
Thanks.